# How to run "tf view_frames" for a remapped tf

Tags: ros, remap, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I remapped `/tf` to `/tf_0`, but I can't get `rosrun tf view_frames` to show me the tree for `/tf_0`. How to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246829/how-to-run-%22tf-view_frames%22-for-a-remapped-tf/) by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2016-10-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-10-31**:
Can you upload a picture of how the tf tree looks like after mapping and the launch file which you did remapping? Also, is there any data from /tf_0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use normal command-line based remapping:

```
rosrun tf view_frames /tf:=/tf_0
```

should do it.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-31**:
Somehow it seems to be this mysterious thing to people, but `tf` is 'just a topic' :).